# How can I Capture Infobox close event ( Google Maps API V3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I need to trigger a function upon closing `Infobox` in `Google maps.` Is there any way to capture Infobox close events ?

Comment: No I mean `Infobox` exactly. http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In documentation of [`InfoWindow`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) there is a `closeclick` event that you can use.

> This event is fired when the close button was clicked.

**Edit**

My mistake talking about `InfoWindow`. However if you look into [`InfoBox` sourcecode](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js) you can see, that it also handles `closeclick` event, so you can use it here too.